# How to Add jar file in android Private libraries?

Tags: java, android

I downloaded Jar file and Copy in Lib folder android, than add library as external jar by Build path in properties, but still i am getting error that "class not found" what is the perfect way to import library? and Most important is why my Jar File not shown in Android Private libraries? How can i do that?

Comment: Do it using the build path ?

Comment: Just drop the jar in your /libs folder, unless you need it to be external for some sort of size issue

Comment: Problem solved Android Private Libraries was not adding Jar in it because there were 2 Support Libraries Jar files in Libs Folder..

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Eclipse, make sure your folder is called libs (plural).

In second place, you can add external jars in your project properties as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjB6z.png)